# how to find the balance in pytezos

Tags: account, python

how to find the balance of an tezos account in pytezos?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can query the node to know if an implicit account `tz{1,2,3}*` is revealed or not.

**Examples**

Revealed Account: https://mainnet.api.tez.ie/chains/main/blocks/head/context/contracts/tz1VSUr8wwNhLAzempoch5d6hLRiTh8Cjcjb/manager_key

Non-revealed account: https://mainnet.api.tez.ie/chains/main/blocks/head/context/contracts/tz1f2k9M3ztqtbCTk5EmEepboEJxksXvafaU/manager_key